# Is possible create new Forum on client side - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, forum

In forum in Drupal 8 is possible for anonymous users to add new topic. But, is there any way for create new forum (is taxonomy) on client side (custom template)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anonymous user can create new forum topic. To perform this functionality, we'll have to follow these steps.

**Step 1** : Allow anonymous user to create forum topic
In this step, we'll allow user to create new forum topic by changing in permissions in admin panel . Here is link of permission page at admin end i.e. /admin/people/permissions
For reference, please check this screenshot.

[image]

**Step 2** : Visit Forms Page
After saving permission, open forum page in browser as anonymous user i.e. /forum

Here, you'll get link to create new **forum topic** without login to drupal.

For reference, please check this screen shot.

[image]

**Step 3** : Create new forum topic

For reference, please check attached screenshot.

[image]

For more technical articles, have a look at http://etutorialz.com